# Array search in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I  have 3 document,

```
{
"category":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"2"},{"id":"3"}]
}

{
"category":[{"id":"1"},{"id":"4"}]
}
{
"category":[]
}
```

How  I can find document which have category.id in (2,3) like mysql,
also which type of DSL query I need to use in java api querybuilder

Answer (score 1):

You can use the bool query with should clause to find all documents which contain either of the requested ids. Here is how the Query DSL would like

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [
               {"term": {
                  "category.id": {
                     "value": "2"
                  }
               }},
               {"term": {
                  "category.id": {
                     "value": "3"
                  }
               }
               }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how you would use the Java API

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("category.id", "2"))
                .should(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("category.id", "1"));
```

If the id field is not-analysed, you can also use the terms query. More info here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's how your query should look like:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "category.id": "1"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "category.id": "2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
{
   "filter": {
        "terms": {
            "category.id": ["2", "3"]
        }
    }
}
```